# Four fundamental forces to explain metabolism

Tags: nuclear-physics, physical-chemistry, biophysics, interactions

Apologies if this question does not make sense. I have tried looking for an answer but couldn't find one and have zero knowledge

I was watching this [video last night which I found fascinating. In it, David Tong talks about our understanding of the universe.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNVQfWC_evg)  This thought crossed my mind - (well it's more two thoughts)

If there are four fundamental forces of interaction, could these be used to explain everything we see around us?

If these fundamental interactions can explain everything, how can we describe the process of metabolism through these fundamental forces of interaction?

Comment: Metabolism = biochemistry, and biochemistry = interactions of atoms = nuclei and electrons interacting through electromagnetism.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the gravitational forces you feel holding you to the earth (or causing the tides, or holding the earth in orbit around the sun, etc.), most of the phenomena that we are directly familiar with are governed by the electromagnetic interaction.  In particular, it is fair to say that [electromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetism) governs essentially all of the standard chemistry that describes metabolism, and more broadly familiar biology.  (Obviously, radiation affects biological entities, so there is space for nuclear interactions, but the majority of phenomena we discuss do not involve those interactions.)  In fact, that wikipedia article I linked says "The electromagnetic force governs the processes involved in chemistry, which arise from interactions between the electrons of neighboring atoms."  Though very broad, that's a pretty fair statement.

In popular media, I would say that [this xkcd comic](https://xkcd.com/435/) describes what we might call the ["hierarchy of sciences"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branches_of_science).  On a related note, I have been present for numerous general lectures given by Stephen Hawking.  In each one, he has said something along the following lines, in reference to the [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation) (which governs the behavior of electrons):

> The Dirac equation describes all of biology and chemistry, and most of physics.

As I've indicated, this is an exaggeration and oversimplification, and he was always tongue-in-cheek bragging just as in the xkcd comic.  But the point he is making is that even though we understand the equation dictating the behavior of the electron, it quickly becomes far too complex to actually use to describe things like biological systems, which is why we still need those more phenomenological sciences.

Comment: That quote, in the form "The underlying physical laws necessary for the mathematical theory of a large part of physics and the whole of chemistry are thus completely known, and the difficulty is only that the exact application of these laws leads to equations much too complicated to be soluble.", dates back to Dirac himself [[*Proc. Roy. Soc. Lond., Ser. A* **123**, p. 714 (1929)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1929.0094), [JSTOR:95222](http://www.jstor.org/stable/95222)].

Comment: The philosophical view illustrated in this post (and in the xkcd strip) is called reductionism. It is worth noting that not everybody agrees: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antireductionism

Comment: I would argue that the view illustrated in this post is consistent with what the wikipedia article refers to as "epistemological antireductionism": that many biological processes are simply too complex to analyze using the Dirac equation, for example, even though we believe them to be ultimately governed by that equation.  Metabolism specifically involves relatively simple chemical reactions.  On the other hand, I don't know that anyone seriously believes that "ontological antireductionism" is relevant to this case — it would be more relevant for such phenomena as consciousness, for example.

Comment: @Mike. I agree that the link I provided is about hard-core antireductionism, which may be over the top. OTOH saying "epistemological" seems to convey the backgroung notion of hard-core reductionism being only temporarily (in the overall progress of science) out of reach. My own view would be "phenomenological non-reductionism" then, i.e. simply noticing for example that even very basic molecular structures cannot be recovered from QM only; in other words that reductionism has to be some kind of philosophical stance, because in practive it does not manifest.